# Pass variable to function parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I need to get a value from an HTML input on the page load. I can successfully get the value form the HTML. I need to pass that variable to the parameter of another function.

This is my HTML code:

```
<input value="3232" id="demo">
```

This is my script with the main function, and I can get the value from the HTML:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('demo').value
  console.log(val)
 });


var fun3 = function(appData){

}
```

I need to pass `var val` to `fun3` and the parameter`appData` should be the reference to val. I should be able to access that `var val` through `appData`. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: fun(val) after console.log(val) should do it. please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: `fun3(val)` below `var = document.getElementById` ... ? Surely can't be that easy of an answer...

Comment: If you call `fun3(val)` it should be enough

Comment: don`t use var to declare variables , use let or const

Comment: You keep asking the same question, apparently using more than one account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9234162/ayb, ignoring all the answers. You won't get the answer you're looking for, all you'll achieve is get banned. The fact that you don't understand how functions parameters work doesn't mean you get to ask the question over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind` to set the value of that input as a default argument for your function

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('demo').value
  fun3 = fun3.bind(null, val);
 });


var fun3 = function(appData){
  console.log(arguments);
}

setTimeout(function(){
  fun3('hey');
  // or just () for default params
  fun3();
}, 0)
```

```html
<input value="3232" id="demo">
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. Just call `fun3` from the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler callback function:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded event handler..');
  var val = document.getElementById('demo').value;
  fun3(val);
});


var fun3 = function(appData) {
  console.log('fun3(...)');
  //you see that val from your event handler function is now referred to as 'appData' locally.
  console.log(appData);
}
```

```html
<input value="3232" id="demo">
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just declare val on the global scope

```
let val = 0;
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  val = document.getElementById('demo').value
  console.log(val)
 });


var fun3 = function(appData){
      console.log(val) // acessible here
}
```

but it's dirty, why can't you just get the value from the input on you funcion? or pass the data into  the function where it's being called?

Answer (score -2):

```
window.appData = val;

fun3() {
   var val = window.appData
...
```

Comment: This is not passing the parameter to a function.